# Getting SQL server to apply where clause with cross join to query in a view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

My first post to stackoverflow (which has helped me hugely over time):

I have a query with a cross join that works fine when I run it with a **where** clause, but takes forever when I place it in a view and apply the **where** clause to the view.

I think the problem is that SQL is not applying the **where** clause to the cross join when the code is encapsulated in a view, and thus ending up with millions of rows (instead of 180 in this case).

The code is below - it is a query which forecasts the future on-hand stock of an item in a warehouse using an average expected monthly usage and a list of incoming orders.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ItemWarehouseStockForecastDaily2]
AS    
SELECT
    fd.AsafterDate
    , iw.idItem
    , iw.idWarehouse
    , iw.OnHandQuantity  
        + SUM(ISNULL(iwio.PurchaseOrderInboundQuantity, 0)
                - iws.AverageMonthlyDemandQuantity / (365.25/12)
            ) OVER (ORDER BY fd.AsafterDate) AS OnHandQuantity
FROM
    (
        ( SELECT CalendarDate Asafterdate 
          FROM Calendar c 
          WHERE c.CalendarDate > GETDATE() 
            AND c.CalendarDate < DATEADD(d, 180, GETDATE())
        ) fd -- This table has 180 rows
        -- This table has 10 million rows - one per item per warehouse
        CROSS JOIN ItemWarehouse iw 
    )
    LEFT JOIN ItemWarehouseDemandFromStockStatisticsMonthly iws
           ON iws.idItem = iw.idItem 
          AND iws.idWarehouse = iw.idWarehouse
    LEFT JOIN ItemWarehouseInboundAndOutboundQuantitiesWithDueDate iwio 
           ON iwio.idItem = iw.idItem 
          AND iwio.idWarehouse = iw.idWarehouse 
          AND iwio.DueDate = fd.Asafterdate
/*
WHERE iw.idItem = 12345
  AND iw.idWarehouse = 67
ORDER BY AsafterDate
*/
```

The commented-out **where** clause makes the query run fast (sub-second) when not in a view (tables cluster by idwarehouse, iditem)

Any/all help and advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have `itemWarehouse` as your base table in your query?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's an execution plan issue. Have you tried adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to your select statement?

Comment: I am not suggesting this is an answer but i am curies if you could tell me the result if you used a table function and not a view!  Ie put all your view code into a table function and run the same tests. Is it the same speed as the view?  I have found that table functions can be a lot better at this sort of thing.

Comment: Hi Stephan, you are right - it is definitely an execution plan issue - the server is not correlating the where clause to the cross join, so instead of 180 rows that part is returning 460 million rows which the server then has to filter back down to 180 using the where clause. I just can't find a way to tell the server!

Comment: Hi @Paul, thanks for the suggestion. A table function value works great as long as I pass **idItem** and **idWarehouse** as parameters. The moment I use the **where** clause only, I am lost again. Unfortunately for the time being I'm publishing the results via an MS Access form after using **union** to combine with historic stock level data, so a view would be extremely convenient..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment yet. However, checking on technet it says that a Cross Join should behave the same as a inner join if you add a where statement (at least for SQL 2008 R2). https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx

Did you check wether the same issue occurs if you use an inner join?

As another alternativ, can you add the constraint directly to the where clause as follows?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ItemWarehouseStockForecastDaily2]
AS    
SELECT
fd.AsafterDate
, iw.idItem
, iw.idWarehouse
, iw.OnHandQuantity  
    + SUM(ISNULL(iwio.PurchaseOrderInboundQuantity, 0)
            - iws.AverageMonthlyDemandQuantity / (365.25/12)
        ) OVER (ORDER BY fd.AsafterDate) AS OnHandQuantity
FROM
(
    ( SELECT CalendarDate Asafterdate 
      FROM Calendar c 
      WHERE c.CalendarDate > GETDATE() 
        AND c.CalendarDate < DATEADD(d, 180, GETDATE())
    ) fd -- This table has 180 rows
    -- Filter right here instead of later:
    INNER JOIN ItemWarehouse iw ON iw.idItem = 12345 AND iw.idWarehouse = 67
)
LEFT JOIN ItemWarehouseDemandFromStockStatisticsMonthly iws
       ON iws.idItem = iw.idItem 
      AND iws.idWarehouse = iw.idWarehouse
LEFT JOIN ItemWarehouseInboundAndOutboundQuantitiesWithDueDate iwio 
       ON iwio.idItem = iw.idItem 
      AND iwio.idWarehouse = iw.idWarehouse 
      AND iwio.DueDate = fd.Asafterdate
```

Comment: Morining @Arnek thank you for your reply! Both the inner join and the where clause work as long as they are incorporated in the query itself. The problem comes when I try to put the query into a view, so that the user can add the where clause (or join) later when looking at an arbitrary item in an arbitrary warehouse. In this case SQL server 2014 does not filter the cross join down to the 180 rows, instead expanding the whole cross join before filtering it down. For now I've worked around it by using a stored procedure which inserts into a table for specific idItem/idWarehouse.